# Flexslider Container Not Resizing

Tags: jquery, html, css

My instance of flexslider isn't resizing. Essentially what happens is the gallery will initiate with the height of the largest image. If an image that has a smaller height than the largest image, the container will stay that height and then just show the image at the top with a lot of margin space at the bottom. I've narrowed it down to the **.flexslider** container, but I'm not sure why it's happening.

Two examples, please ignore the navigation, I'm using the wordpress unit test currently:
http://themes.appearlythemes.com/dev/?p=555
http://themes.appearlythemes.com/dev/?p=1707

The html markup is this:

```
<section class="post-media">
    <div class="flexslider">
       <ul class="slides">
       ...
       </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

I have a wordpress loop that echoes the post attachment link in a list tag inside the unordered list tag.

I've spent hours googling this problem, as well as searching StackOverflow, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why you need the following declaration but it works with it:

```
.flexslider {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Didn't realize it could be that simple. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked adding

> smoothHeight: true

to the jquery declaration. So it was:

```
$('#slider').flexslider({
        animation: "fade",
        controlNav: false,
        animationLoop: false,
        slideshow: false,
        sync: "#carousel",
        smoothHeight: true
    });
```